# Copy Paste area is not the same size VBA 1004 Error

Tags: excel, vba

This code is throwing error.

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(14, 7), Cells(NewRow, 8)).Copy
ws.Range("A1").Offset(rn, 6).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Keeps on saying the size is not the same. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can (re-)use a generic sub to copy values plus avoid copy/paste --> `copyRangeValues`

Using the generic sub avoids a possible error when resizing the target range. If it is correct once it is correct for all other calls as well.

Plus another tip: use variable names that explain what the variable contains. `rn` is such a non-self-explaining variable ... Propably this is the source of your error ...

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub copyWhatever()

'ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(14, 7), Cells(NewRow, 8)).Copy
'ws.Range("A1").Offset(rn, 6).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Dim rgSource As Range
Set rgSource = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(14, 7), Cells(NewRow, 8))

Dim cTarget As Range
Set cTarget = ws.Range("A1").Offset(rn, 6)

copyRangeValues rgSource, cTarget

End Sub


'This is the generic sub that can be re-used for all copy tasks
Public Sub copyRangeValues(rgSource As Range, cTarget As Range)
'cTarget = cell where the copied values should start = top left corner

With rgSource
    cTarget.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value2 = .Value2
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Value` property of the `Range` object to paste values.

Reference the "source" range and make sure the "target" one has the same number of rows and columns

```
With ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(14, 7), Cells(NewRow, 8))
    ws.Range("A1").Offset(rn, 6).Resize(.Rows.Count, .columns.Count).Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: copy is obsolete when using value ...

Comment: @Ike, yeah, it was a leftout of previous code
thanks